# Bigquery Error with empty Location and Message

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am using golang bigquery client to insert data into bigquery.

Below is a part of my code.

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "project_id", option.WithCredentialsFile("google-credentials.json"))
if err != nil {
     panic(err.Error())
}

Inserter = client.Dataset("data-set").Table("table_name").Inserter()

if err := Inserter.Put(ctx, body); err != nil {
        if pmErr, ok := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError); ok {
            for _, rowInsertionError := range pmErr {
                log.Println(rowInsertionError.Errors)
            }
        }
        return nil, err
    }
```

And I get **error** without location and message.

```
    2022/03/25 10:03:13 {Location: ""; Message: ""; Reason: "invalid"}
    2022/03/25 10:03:13 {Location: ""; Message: ""; Reason: "invalid"}
    2022/03/25 10:03:13 {Location: ""; Message: ""; Reason: "invalid"}
    2022/03/25 10:03:13 {Location: ""; Message: ""; Reason: "invalid"}
```

I believe I am doing something wrong.
But can't seem to find where to look at from those error messages.

What is the cause of bigquery error without location and message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried running the code and sample data found in [bigquery golang example](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#example-Inserter.Put), I included the multi error printing and I can't reproduce your error. 1.) What is printed if you did `log.Println(err)`? 2.) Does `body` contain the rows you want to insert? 3.) How is `body` defined in the code? 4.) Can you share your code that includes defining the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If `body` is a `struct` that has `"bigquery"` tags but doesn't have `"json"` tags, you may have issues as the library will try to make a request with JSON body and will need those tags in order to properly build the request body.
In short,

this **does** work:

```
type TableRecord struct {
    name    string `bigquery:"name" json:"name"`
}
```

this **doesn't** work:

```
type TableRecord struct {
    name    string `bigquery:"name"
}
```

I have experienced receiving "error without location and message" as you described in this situation.